# How to upload image using camel-jetty component

Tags: java, apache-camel, image-upload

I am creating a image file uploader using camel-jetty component. Image will be attached in the request body as multi-part form data and it has to  be uploaded to S3.

**This is my route :** from("jetty:http://localhost:8889/imageservice?enableMultipartFilter=true").process(processor);

But before the request reaches the processor, it throws the below exception. I searched in google but getting nowhere. Please help me solve this problem.

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Cannot populate attachments
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.AttachmentHttpBinding.populateAttachments(AttachmentHttpBinding.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.readRequest(DefaultHttpBinding.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.<init>(HttpMessage.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.service(CamelContinuationServlet.java:134)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter.doFilter(MultiPartFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelFilterWrapper.doFilter(CamelFilterWrapper.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.AttachmentHttpBinding.populateAttachments(AttachmentHttpBinding.java:48)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Just a thought, why would you not use the S3 Camel component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the NullPointerException stacktrace...  When the org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser parses the request into parts, one of those parts is null.  This indicates there's something wrong with the format of the request...

Try setting on the jetty url the property 'disableStreamCache' to true. Per http://camel.apache.org/jetty, "By default Camel will cache the Jetty input stream to support reading it multiple times to ensure it Camel can retrieve all data from the stream. However you can set this option to true when you for example need to access the raw stream, such as streaming it directly to a file or other persistent store."